# Swift: I used these arrays/dictionaries correctly right?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have no idea why I'm getting this error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'result' is immutable. Can someone help?

```
class Student {
    var name: String
    var yearOfGraduation: Int
    var grade: Grade
    
    init(name: String, yearOfGraduation: Int, grade: Grade) {
        self.name = name
        self.yearOfGraduation = yearOfGraduation
        self.grade = grade
    }
}
// Create a function called createYearDictionary that takes in an array of Student objects
// (argument name students) and returns a dictionary that maps year of graduation to an array of
// student names that graduate in that year.
//
// Example: createYearDictionary(kanye, kim, travis, kylie, khloe) would output
// [2019: ["Kanye West", "Khloe Kardashian"], 2020: ["Kim Kardashian"], 2021: ["Travis Scott"], 2022: ["Kylie Jenner"]]
//
// When you're done, uncomment the code block below and ensure that the test cases pass.
//
// Hint: What should the return type be? Remember that the type of a dictionary is
// [TypeA: TypeB], where TypeA and TypeB could be String, Int, Bool, String arrays, etc.
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    var result = [Int:[String]]()
    
    for student in students {
        if (result[student.yearOfGraduation] == []) {
            result[student.yearOfGraduation] = [student.name]}
        else {
            result[student.yearOfGraduation].append(student.name)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to return a type `[Int: [Student]]` but the example output states that what you should return is `[Int: [String]]` therefore you will need to pass the value of the `.name` property of `Student` objects. Also you can use `default` parameter in the dictionary subscript to skip the if-else clause.

```swift
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    var result = [Int: [String]]()
    for student in students {
        if result[student.yearOfGraduation] == nil {
            result[student.yearOfGraduation] = [student.name]
        } else { 
            result[student.yearOfGraduation]?.append(student.name)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

or simply with [dictionary subscript with default value](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript)

```swift
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    var result = [Int: [String]]()
    for student in students {
        result[student.yearOfGraduation, default: []].append(student.name)
    }
    return result
}
```

more on [Subscripts](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html)

Comment: this is called Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value

Comment: Can you look at my updated code? I just edited the post. I made similar changes but my else block is incorrect for some reason.

Comment: a dictionary subscript returns an optional value (`[String]`) so you will need to add `?` before `.append(student.name)`. You can try to use the one-liner from my answer.

Comment: @witekbobrowski your code works but my else statement still doesn't work. I wrote         else {result[student.yearOfGraduation]?.append(student.name)}

Comment: @witekbobrowski also what is a dictionary subscript? I thought dictionaries are just key-value pairs. is the subscript the value?

Comment: oh I see the problem, you have a bad if statement, rather than checking for a empty array `[]` you need to compare it to `nil` let me just update my answer

Comment: @witekbobrowski oh shoot, i see, yeah. That was my bad. Sorry to ask but do you mind explaining why I need a ? before .append(student.name)?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to a documentation where you can read more about subscripts

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your `createYearDictionary(students:)` function, using `init(grouping:by:)` of `Dictionary`:

```
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    Dictionary(grouping: students) { $0.yearOfGraduation }
        .mapValues { $0.map { $0.name } }
}
```

And from Swift 5.2 using KeyPaths:

```
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    Dictionary(grouping: students, by: \.yearOfGraduation)
        .mapValues { $0.map(\.name) }
}
```

or using just `reduce(into:_:)` function:

```
func createYearDictionary(students: [Student]) -> [Int: [String]] {
    students.reduce(into: [:]) { result, student in
        result[student.yearOfGraduation, default: []].append(student.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary(grouping: students, by: \.yearOfGraduation)`

Comment: Btw Swift is a type inferred language `reduce(into: [:])` and you can omit `return`

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, that's a mistype. Thank you.

Comment: @LeoDabus well, I hadn't have the chance to use your last suggestion. Interesting thing to learn. Thank you.